# R - sub to remove the special character if in first position

Tags: r, special-characters, remove-if

I would like to remove the symbol "|" but only when it is at the beginning of a sentence (e.g., I want "|pediatrics" to become "pediatrics" but "pediatrics|clinical" should not be changed.

I tried

```
sub('[|[:alnum:]]','', "word")
```

which works well in the case where "|" is indeed at the beginning of the sentence, but removes the first letter when it is not present (i.e.,

> sub('[|[:alnum:]]','', "|pediatrics")

returns pediatrics as desired but

> sub('[|[:alnum:]]','', "pediatrics")

returns ediatrics...

Any help would be extremely valuable!
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `^` to specify start of the string and since `|` has a special meaning in regex, escape it with `\\`. With `sub` you may do -

```
x <- c('|pediatrics', 'pediatrics|clinical')
y <- sub('^\\|', '', x)
y
#[1] "pediatrics"          "pediatrics|clinical"
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help! I was missing the need for \\ before | :)